# Multiple Forms with Submit through a single page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm after some advice on the best way to approach this. On a page I have 5 sections which contain a form, each section also has a file upload form at the end of it. this is an example of a layout

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <!--Form 1 with all the Inputs -->
        <button type="submit" name="form1">Confirm Section</button>
    </form>
    <form> upload file </form> <!-- using Dropzonejs -->

    <form>
        <!--Form 2 with all the Inputs -->
        <button type="submit" name="form2">Confirm Section</button>
    </form>
    <form> upload file </form> <!-- using Dropzonejs -->

    <form>
        <!--Form 3 with all the Inputs -->
        <button type="submit" name="form3">Confirm Section</button>
    </form>
    <form> upload file </form> <!-- using Dropzonejs -->

    <form>
        <!--Form 4 with all the Inputs -->
        <button type="submit" name="form4">Confirm Section</button>
    </form>
    <form> upload file </form> <!-- using Dropzonejs -->

    <form>
        <!--Form 5 with all the Inputs -->
        <button type="submit" name="form5">Confirm Section</button>
    </form>
    <form> upload file </form> <!-- using Dropzonejs -->

    <!-- button to continue to another page -->
    <button type="submit" name="continue">Continue</button>


    <script type="text/javascript">myjscode.js</script>     

</body>
</html>
```

I use this jquery to act when the submit button is pressed on each section, there are one of these for each submit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form1form').on('submit',function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'includes/form1uploads.php',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                document.getElementById('showhidedropzonesection').style.display = 'block';
            },
            error:function(data){
                $(".alert-danger'").show().fadeOut(5000);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

When I post the form1 details say, it then $_POST all inputs and uploads to the database, I keep a couple of fields in the $_SESSION so that I can use them on the next forms, but when I submit the next form the data that is put into the $_POST doesn't store anything and submits a blank row to the database.

Now because you can't have  within  how is the best way to approach this so that I can have an input section form, then my upload file form and then again on to another input form as I have set out.

Or is there a better way to approach it?

I've set it out like this because, when the user will get to the end of form1 they will need to upload a file, showing evidence of the input, and the same for the next sections

Comment: You control only one form with your js

Comment: I've set a js up for each submit

Answer (score 0):

I would just use ajax to submit data every time it is changed and the < html > that makes up the form will be re structured by another .php page that the ajax is POSTing to returning the correct html layout

http://www.sanwebe.com/2011/12/making-simple-jquery-ajax-contact-form

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at the example, I don't quite understand your point of "the < html > that makes up the form will be re structured by another .php page that the ajax is POSTing to returning the correct html layout" can you explain that a bit, thanks :-)